# Node mocha/chai test to see if a folder exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test the creation of a folder of a specific path. I am able to properly check if the folder exists before creating it, but when I run the same check after it's been created it returns undefined.

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var assert = require('chai').assert;

var fs = require('fs');
var dir = './tmp';

describe('Create a folder and check if it\'s been created', function(){

    it('check if folder has been created, if no folder exists, then create one: ', function(done){

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }
    done();
    });

    it('check to see if folder is there', function() {
        if (fs.existsSync(dir)){
            assert.isOk();
        }else{
            assert.fail();
        }
    done();
    });
});
```

the result is:

1 passing (23ms)
  1 failing

1) Create a folder and check if it's been created check to see if folder is there:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to be truthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`assert.isOk()`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_isok) doesn't do what you think. It is not an always passing assertion; instead, it checks the argument you pass in to see if it's truthy. Since you're not passing anything in, the value is `undefined`, hence "expected undefined to be truthy."

You can just leave off the assertion; the test will pass if there are no failing assertions, so there's no need for a dummy always-passing assertion. Or you can pass the result of `existsSync` to `isOk`:

```
it('check to see if folder is there', function() {
  assert.isOk(fs.existsSync(dir));
});
```